# Why can't auto be return type of a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

My question is, why can't the return type of a function be deduced ? , or more simply why the following code gives error :

```
auto myfunc(int a)
{
int a = 12;
return a;
}
```

Why this isn't valid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a feature in C++14 , You can try it with GCC 4.9 or clang by setting the -std=c++1y flag.

Live Example : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00b8b708d6f0f45b

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html

Comment: Just a precision: it's not upcoming, *ISO/IEC 14882:2014(E)* was issued in August 2014 and all major compilers support most of it's features for a while.

Answer (score 2):

It is allowed in C++14 (and is called automatic return type deduction), you may enable it in your compiler with `std=c++1y` for now.

You can use the trailing return type if your compiler supports c++11 but not c++14 :

```
auto myfunc(int a) -> int
{
int b = a;
return a;
}
```